# springboot 2.6.5 + springcloud 2021.0.1 start failed with external tomcat but succeed in embeded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

originally I used springboot 2.4.9 + springcloud 2020.0.4 which worked fine with external tomacat but for springboot 2.6.5 + springcloud 2021.0.1, it starts failed with external tomcat but succeed in embedded tomcat. It failed to register on the eureka server.

```
springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(830) - Application run failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.56]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.56]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.56]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.56]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:420) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:266) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
```

Answer (score 1):

### I encounter the question that is similar with you and my version of spring-webmvc.jar is 5.3.18. Have you sloved this question?

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException**
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
at com.huawei.devcloud.octopusjoblogs.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes!/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [OctopusJobLogs.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [OctopusJobLogs.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [OctopusJobLogs.jar:?]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [OctopusJobLogs.jar:?]
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]**
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:420) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:266) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
... 23 more

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).